# Running Android Studio Volley in different API levels

Tags: android, android-volley

The app I made ran on different API levels but the volley library only works API level 26.

I was puzzled when I can't login in the app using my phone (android 9) but a later model works just fine. I found out that I can only login in Android 8 phones (API level 26). I tested multiple virtual devices with different API levels and API level 26 let's me login and the rest just doesn't work. I was wondering how can I make volley library work on API level 26 and higher.

Edit: It was a big mistake for me but I now enabled the log for errors and I found these.

(Using http://)
[image]

(Using https://)
[image]

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.studentplanner"
        minSdk 26
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    buildFeatures {

        viewBinding true

    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    namespace 'com.example.studentplanner'
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.github.xabaras:RecyclerViewSwipeDecorator:1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha04'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line in your application tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        ...>
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```